# Boost Options - Get application name

Tags: c++, boost, command-line

Is there a simple way to get the application name using Boost (maybe with `boost::program_options`?)

The thing will be like this:

Having `argv[0] = "c:\foo\bar\appname.exe"`

I want to have `var1 = "appname"`

Comment: Well, there's `basename(3)`, although that's admittedly not very Boosty.

Comment: If you really wanted to be fancy, you could use `boost.regex` to parse the path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use boost::filesystem to extract the name from the path. that would look something like this:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

boost::filesystem::path p = argv[0];
std::string var1 = p.stem().string();
```